# Have I been using `ReactElement` in the correct way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I’ve built an app with "components" that all begin like this:

```
export const SomeComponent = (props: SomeComponentProps): React.ReactElement => {
return (
      <>
        <div>some content</div>
      </>
    )
}
```

However now I’ve been Googling and it would seem as though this is not a "component" but an "element".

I’m having some difficulty telling if I’ve built my app correctly, all of my TSX/JSX files are set up like this and use "ReactElement" but an lot of results on the web show me things called "components" with a render method in them.

Should all of my components/elements in my app start with `React.ReactElement` or have I done this entirely wrong?

Comment: _"...it would seem as though this is not a "Component" but an "Element"."_ It's a function which _returns_ an element, as the return type makes clear, which is a function-based component. The other kind of component is a class-based component, which has the render method (also returning an element). See e.g. https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Component.

Comment: [memo](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo) is the equivalent of `shouldComponentUpdate` for function components.

Comment: First question: use `React.ReactNode` it's very good and its also includes `ReactElement` and Second question: `use React.memo`, let me know if this short answer is ok for you so I can post answer respectively in detail.

Comment: @NishargShah @RobinZigmond  `memo` is exactly what I'm looking for thanks! I'd love to know more about `React.ReactNode` is possible. I think the ultimate question is, have I gone abotu building my app in the wrong way using `ReactElement`s for all the components.

Comment: One way or another you're going to be writing something that returns elements, or you're not going to have much of an app. If you mean function- vs. class-based, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61859809/3001761. If you just mean as a return type, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58123398/3001761.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to type the return type of React components. So just remove the `: React.ReactElement` part and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

**First Question**

`React.ReactNode` is everything that `react` can offer. It can be string, number, boolean, null, undefined, fragment, portal, ReactElement, or an array of the ReactNode.

so If you look into the type of `ReactNode`, it will look something like below.

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

**Second Question**

The answer is `React.memo`, `useMemo`, and `React.memo` is different so please take note of it.

No one can explain you more than docs, please refer new doc: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo